# Upgrade PHP to the newest version without reinstalling the XAMPP on Mac Os

Tags: php, xampp

Is there any way to update XAMPP's PHP version from 5.5.15 to the newest one without reinstalling the whole XAMPP on the macOS High Sierra?

Comment: Did you get it to work? I had to reinstall MacOS for time machine backup, because PHP 7 upgrade broke my XAMPP / MySQL ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to download needed version of php, put it in the directory with php files. Then rename current version in that folder prefixing it with something like _. Then xamp should see new versions of php. This worked for MAMP so i think should work with xamp too.

Comment: What is the path to PHP file for XAMPP on mac?